# mysql: do left join on certain table if column has value

Tags: mysql

I have a few tables:  `devices`, `acccessories` and `repairs`.

`Repairs` has a field in it called: `item_type` and one called `ref_id`

`item_type` can have value of '1' meaning it's a device or '2' meaning it's an accessory.

If `repairs.item_type = 1` I want to do a join on that table where `repairs.ref_id = devices.id`.
If `repairs.item_type = 2` I want to do a join on that table where `repairs.ref_id = acccessories.id`.

I'm not sure how to do that.

```
SELECT * 
FROM repairs
LEFT JOIN repairs.ref_id = (if repairs.item_type = 1 then devices.id; if repairs.item_type = 2 then accessories.id)
```

Is there a way to do this, or do I need to do a `UNION ALL` like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM repairs
LEFT JOIN repairs.ref_id = devices.id 
WHERE repairs.item_id = '1'

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM repairs
LEFT JOIN repairs.ref_id = accessories.id 
WHERE repairs.item_id = '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

join `devices` and `accessories` tables to `repair` table.

```
select t1.*
from repairs t1
left join devices t2 on t2.id =  t1.ref_id
left join accessories t3 on t3.id = t1.ref_id
and t1.item_type in (1, 2)
```